# How to provide short path for graphics in included file?

Tags: graphics, include

I am creating a research diary using LaTeX that has input files stored in folder A

```
Diary
   |
   |+ Diary.tex
   |
   |+ January
   |     |
   |     |+ January.tex 
   |     |
   |     |+ Figures
   |          |
   |          |+ Figure_A1.pdf
   |          |
   |          |+ Figure_A2.pdf
   |
   |+ February
   |     |
   |     |+ February.tex 
   |     |
   |     |+ Figures
   |          |
   |          |+ Figure_B1.pdf
   |          |
   |          |+ Figure_B2.pdf
   |
   |+ March
        |
        |+ March.tex 
        |
        |+ Figures
              |
              |+ Figure_C1.pdf
              |
              |+ Figure_C2.pdf
```

At present I am placing the files January, February, March as input files in Diary.tex as shown below:

**Diary.tex**

```
\documentclass[15pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}


\begin{document}
    \title{\rmfamily\normalfont\spacedallcaps{Research diary}}
    \author{\spacedlowsmallcaps{nxkr}}
    \date{} % no date
    \clearpage\maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \include{./January/January}
    \include{./February/February}   
    \include{./March/March}
\pagebreak
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

**January.tex**

```
\section*{January}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{./January/Figures/Figure_A1.pdf}
\caption{OFigure_A1}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_A1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{./January/Figures/Figure_A2.pdf}
\caption{OFigure_A2}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_A2}
\end{figure}
```

**February.tex**

```
\section*{February}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{./February/Figures/Figure_B1.pdf}
\caption{OFigure_B1}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_B1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{./February/Figures/Figure_B2.pdf}
\caption{OFigure_B2}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_B2}
\end{figure}
```

**March.tex**

```
\section*{March}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{./March/Figures/Figure_C1.pdf}
\caption{OFigure_A1}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_C1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{./March/Figures/Figure_C2.pdf}
\caption{OFigure_C2}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_C2}
\end{figure}
```

Do I have to provide the full path directory of the graphic file like:

```
./January/Figures/Figure_A1.pdf
./January/Figures/Figure_A2.pdf
```

Is there any way I can provide just the child directory path like:

```
./Figures/Figure_A1.pdf
./Figures/Figure_A2.pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, after loading the `graphicx` package, we use the `\graphicspath` command to extend searchable paths and their order of searching (the TeX engine goes from top to bottom folders).

After you change the underscore in your other three TeX files in captions to `\_` and delete those subfolders, this main TeX file should work for you just fine (tested with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass[15pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ 
   {January/Figures/}
   {February/Figures/}
   {March/Figures/}
   }

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \title{\rmfamily\normalfont\spacedallcaps{Research diary}}
    \author{\spacedlowsmallcaps{nxkr}}
    \date{} % no date
    \clearpage\maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \include{./January/January}
    \include{./February/February}   
    \include{./March/March}
\pagebreak
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

The `January.tex` file:

```
\section*{January}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Figure_A1.pdf}
\caption{OFigure\_A1}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_A1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Figure_A2.pdf}
\caption{OFigure\_A2}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_A2}
\end{figure}
```

The `February.tex` file:

```
\section*{February}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Figure_B1.pdf}
\caption{OFigure\_B1}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_B1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Figure_B2.pdf}
\caption{OFigure\_B2}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_B2}
\end{figure}
```

The `March.tex` file:

```
\section*{March}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Figure_C1.pdf}
\caption{OFigure\_A1}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_C1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Figure_C2.pdf}
\caption{OFigure\_C2}
\end{center}
\label{fig:figure_C2}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put a `\graphicspath` command in the preamble. In the argument, you can indicate the path(s) where the graphics to be included are to be found.

```
 \graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
```

Then you can enter in your document, for example,

```
\includegraphics{Figure_A1.pdf}
```

Comment: I'm curious: why the downvote?